# Update if value not undefined - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update the value if key in the payload should have some value (not undefined or any false value). I don't want to check every value that makes code lengthy.

```
await Parent.findByIdAndUpdate(
    payload.TID,
    {
      healthTests: payload.foo,
      otherHealthtest: payload.bar,
    },
    { new: true, fields: { updatedAt: 0, createdAt: 0, __v: 0 } },
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entires()` to iterate keys and values and build your `updateObj`:

```
let updateObj = {};

for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(payload)){
    if(value !== undefined){
        updateObj[key] = value;
    }
}

await Parent.findByIdAndUpdate(
    payload.TID, updateObj,
    { new: true, fields: { updatedAt: 0, createdAt: 0, __v: 0 } },
);
```

example:

```js
let payload = { foo: 1, bar: undefined, baz: 3};
let updateObj = {};

for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(payload)){
    if(value !== undefined){
        updateObj[key] = value;
    }
}

console.log(updateObj);
```

Comment: I think you did not get my point. I wanna update the value only in case if the payload have some value for that key. I don't care about if its already exists or not.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "some value", you can easily replace the condition with `healthTests: { $ne: null }` or something like that, can you show some examples ?

Comment: suppose, if request `payload.foo = "xyz"` I want to update `healthTests` in that case but if `payload.foo` is undefined(or there is no key in payload like that) I do not want to update `healthTests`.

Comment: @imrvasishtha sorry, misunderstood your question, see my modified answer